# Command not found in Bash's IF-ELSE condition when using [! -d "$DIR"]

Tags: linux, bash, unix, directory

I have a code like this

```
#!/bin/bash 
DIR="test_dir/";
if [! -d "$DIR"]; then
    # If it doesn't create it
    mkdir $DIR
fi
```

But why executing it gave me this:

```
./mycode.sh: line 16: [!: command not found
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: The name `[` is the name of a command, not random punctuation.  Just as you need a space between `cat` and `/etc/passwd` in `cat/etc/passwd`, so you need a space between `[` (the command name) and `!` (one of its arguments).  Similarly, the last argument must be `]`.  This requirement goes back to ancient history (7th Edition UNIX™ circa 1978, or earlier) when the shell did not have a `test` (aka `[`) built-in and the only `test` command was `/bin/test` and its (hard) link `/bin/[`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add space between [ and !. And before ] as well.

```
#!/bin/bash 
DIR="test_dir/";
if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
    # If it doesn't create it
    mkdir $DIR
fi
```

It's also a good idea to quote your variable:

```
    mkdir "$DIR"
```

Answer (score 11):

Add some spaces:

```
if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
#   ^           ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also attempt to simply by saying:

```
test -d "${dir}" || mkdir "${dir}"
```

This would create the directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Or, even easier: `mkdir -p "$DIR"` (using the upper-case name as in the question).  This creates all directories needed on the path, but succeeds if the directory already exists.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yup, `mkdir -p foo` by itself doesn't do any harm.